# Presto: Convert vachar to datetime 2019-03-01 08:13:50,704

Tags: sql, presto

How to convert varchar of format `2019-03-01 08:13:50,704` to datetime in presto

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way already:

```
CAST(date_format(date_parse(cast(dateid as varchar(23)), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s,%p'), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s,%p') AS DATETIME)
```

See [date_parse](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse)

Comment: its throws error
```java.sql.SQLException: Query failed: line 1:132: mismatched input ')' expecting {'.', '[', 'AS', 'AT', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', 'NOT', 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE', 'IS', 'FILTER', 'OVER', '=', NEQ, '<', '<=', '>', '>=', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '||'}```

Comment: `date_parse` doesn't support parsing milliseconds, you need to use `parse_datetime ` (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#parse_datetime), like this: `CAST(parse_datetime('2019-03-01 08:13:50,704', 'yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss,SSS') AS timestamp)` (I added `CAST`, because `parse_datetime` returns a `timestamp with time zone` and here likely `timestamp` is needed).